# Netcat using exec() Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, exec, netcat

I would like to use netcat in JavaScript by using exec function. I wrote below function when I run it  I am not seeing anything on my command line.

```
  const { exec } = require('child_process');
  var myScript = exec('nc -l 87',
          (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              console.log(stdout);

              console.log(stderr);
              if (error !== null) {
                  console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
              }
          });
```

PS:  I know the netcat module in node.js but I want to use it with exec function.

Comment: what's connecting to it? are you running this with root privileges since you're using a port less than 1024?

Comment: My command works as expected from command line. But the problem is it is not working (i.e., printing out anything) when I used it with exec.

Comment: so, you don't `sudo` ... you running as `root`? and is there something connecting to that `nc`?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I think the issue was related to using zsh instead of bash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, problem were related with the using zsh instead of using bash. If you run your node application in the bash shell the application is giving the expected output.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).